# Ist „abonnierbar“ ein gültiges Wort?

Tags: adjective, vocabulary, adjective-ending

Im Zusammenhang mit der Benennung einiger Programmteile ist uns aufgefallen, dass es weder im [Deutschen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/abonnieren) noch im [Englischen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subscribe?q=subscribe) das Wort *„abonnierbar“* (bzw. *“subscribable”*) zu geben scheint. Auf der anderen Seite sind die Wörter [greifbar](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/greifbar), [handelbar](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/handelbar) und [schwenkbar](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwenkbar) (alles Beispiele) sehr wohl im Duden zu finden.

Daraus ergeben sich für mich mehrere Fragen:

1. Was ist der richtige Begriff bzw. die korrekte grammatikalische Regel zur Bildung solcher „Adjektivierungen“?
2. Müssen diese Wörter im Duden stehen, damit sie „gültig“ sind? Verstanden werden sie ja trotzdem.
3. Falls *abonnierbar* kein „gültiges“ deutsches Wort sein sollte, gibt es Alternativen?

Comment: "subscribable" klingt m.E. schon gültig.

Comment: Google ngrams findet durchaus einige (wenige), auch in öffentlichen Verlautbarungen auftauchende Vorkommen von *subscribable*, allerdings nicht für Zeitungen, sondern Staatsanleihen. *abonnierbar* wird aber nicht gefunden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. [Adjektivableitung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/To-A-Intro.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules111) (=ich mache ein Adjektiv), [Suffigierung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/Intro.html#Anchor-Suffigierung-49575)(=durch Anhängen eines Suffix)
2. Nein, ein Wort muss nicht im Duden (und im Englischen auch nicht in den Oxford Dictionaries) stehen, damit es "gültig" ist. Gerade im Deutschen, wo wir sowas wie "zusammengesetzte Nomen" haben, ist es schier unmöglich, alles im Duden aufzuführen. Wichtig ist, einzig, dass das Wort verstanden wird.
3. *Abbonabel*? Ok, Spaß beiseite. Manchmal gibt es Alternativen, oder gar bessere Wortwahlen (*akzeptierbar* -> *akzeptabel*), aber im Zweifel wird der Satz umformuliert.

> Dieses Magazin ist nicht abonnierbar.
>
> > Dieses Magazin kann man nicht abonnieren.
> >     Dieses Magazin ist nicht zu abonnieren.

Die Endung *[-bar](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/bar.html)* ist übrigens die häufigst vorkommende Endung, wenn aus einem Verb ein Adjektiv gemacht wird. Also *abonnieren* wird *abonnierbar*.

---

Apart: [Subscribable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Subscribable) gibt es in mindestens einem Dictionary.

Comment: Das beantwortet meine Frage, danke! Dennoch eine Kurze Anmerkung zu 3.: Da wir das Wort innerhalb von Programmcode verwenden ist das mit dem Satz umformulieren nicht so einfach... Sätze gibt es da nicht! ;) Tut aber hier nicht's zur Sache.

Answer (score 1):

Beim Programmieren würde ich nicht so viel Augenmerk auf Grammatik legen. Wenn Abonnierbar passt und im Team verstanden wird, würde ich das nehmen, insbesondere, wenn da ein Entwurfsmuster o.ä. umgesetzt wird, wo diese Formulierung passt.

Comment: In der Tat, ich hielte es sogar durchaus für normal und angemessen englischsprachige Bezeichner zu verwenden, denn am Ende steht da sonst doch eh ein Mischmasch wie *if X.abonnierbar then*, so dass *if X.subscribable then* (oder vielleicht *if X.canBeSubscribed then*) am Ende weniger verwirrt.

Comment: Aus der Frage geht nicht hervor, ob es hier um interne Bezeichnungen oder für Benutzer sichtbare Texte in der Programmoberfläche geht.